# lag meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> The U.S. lags countries such as South Korea and Germany, according to an Economist Intelligence Unit study, in preparing students to work with computational thinking, AI, and robotics.

This is a sentence from an article from *The Atlantic* that I was reading, but I don't quite understand what "lags" mean here (despite having searched up Oxford dictionary). Does it mean that the US is lagging behind S.Korea and Germany in preparing its students, or does it mean that the US accepts and prepares a lot of Korean & German students? I had never seen "lag" without behind before, so I'm not too sure.

Comment: You should always check multiple dictionaries, not just one. See for example [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lag) or [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lag).

Comment: @userr2684291: OP doesn't necessarily need to check *multiple* dictionaries. It's true that ***only one*** of the example usages in OP's cited [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lag) doesn't actually include the word ***behind***, but even that one single example is enough to prove the point: ***I can tell the Labour members why they are lagging in the polls.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, but that's not really the point I wanted to controvert; namely, *lag* is used transitively in the example the asker is asking about, while the ODE there labels the verb clearly as licensing *[NO OBJECT]*. The other dictionaries contain transitive definitions of the verb.

Comment: @userr2684291: oic. Yeah, well I suppose all I can say on that front is that Oxford Dictionaries are simply ***wrong***. Putting aside the question of whether it makes sense to differentiate between verbs that can attach to an "object" ***with or without*** a preposition / adverb (such as ***behind*** here), it certainly makes no sense to claim that ***to lag*** is a "no object" verb. You can lag the competition (definitely an "object", by anyone's standards), or you can be lagging ***in*** the polls (definitely *not* an "object", imho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lag, in this context, means "to be behind" or "to go slower".  It means Germany and Korea are ahead of the USA in preparing students for AI.